# Image not showing any bands

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to make a list of Sentinel-2 image for each year from 2015-2023, each of output layer are the years. But the result shows image doesn't have any bands.

How can i fix it?

My GEE source: https://code.earthengine.google.com/10b8afcb4ad42e8ae2a48835c795aecf

My code:

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
var qa = image.select('QA60');
// Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
// Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
var ls1c = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
              .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2019-12-31')
              // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
              .map(maskS2clouds)
              .filterBounds(DiAn)    
              .map(function(a){
               var timeStart = a.get('system:time_start');
                return a.set('year', ee.Algorithms.If(timeStart, ee.Image(a).date().get('year'), a)); 
              })
 var ls2a = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
              .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2023-12-31')
              // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
              .map(maskS2clouds)
              .filterBounds(DiAn)
              .map(function(a){
               var timeStart = a.get('system:time_start');
                return a.set('year', ee.Algorithms.If(timeStart, 
 ee.Image(a).date().get('year'), a)); 
              })
 print(ls1c)
 print(ls2a)
 var list = ee.List([])   
 for (var a = 2015; a <2024; a++) {
 if (a < 2020) {
    var fills1c = ls1c.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', a).median()
    var ls1cfinal = fills1c.set('year', a)
                       .set('product', 'LS1C')
    list = list.add(ls1cfinal)
}else{
    var fills2a = ls2a.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', a).median()
    var ls2afinal = fills2a.set('year', a)
                       .set('product', 'LS2A')
    list = list.add(ls2afinal)
 }
}       
print(list)
var finalCol = ee.ImageCollection(list).map(function(a){
            return a.set('bands', ee.Image(a).bandNames().length())
})
                 .filterMetadata('bands', 'equals', 0)
print(finalCol)  
for(var a = 2015; a < 2024; a++){
Map.addLayer(finalCol.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', a), {}, 'Năm'+' '+a, false)}
Map.centerObject(DiAn, 12)
```

[image: Output]